# JAXP with Xerces with ignores xsi:schemaLocation attribute?

Tags: java, xerces, jaxp

I've tried creating a SAXParser, but any xsi:schemaLocation attributes in the instance document are ignored.  Does Xerces not support this feature when using JAXP?

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
...

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setSchema(schema);      // schema already created beforehand
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);

SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                            
XMLReader parser = sp.getXMLReader();
parser.setEntityResolver( new DefaultResolver());    // the entity resolver never gets invoked
parser.setErrorHandler(new SAXErrorHandler()); 
parser.setContentHandler(new TestHandler());
parser.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(dataPath.toFile())));
```

So everything works in terms of parsing and validating the document, except when there are xsi:schemaLocation attributes, these are completely getting ignored.

If I use Xerces directly, it will invoke its entity resolver.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior as per JAXP specification.

To use `xsi:schemaLocaton` or `xsi:noNamespceSchemaLocation` hints during validation, the method [newSchema](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema--) should be used instead of [newSchema(schema)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema-javax.xml.transform.Source-).